# Windows 8 advanced startup command prompt documentation

Tags: windows-8

I take part in development of disk filter driver.

Windows 8 has special recovery mode: Advanced Startup Command Prompt.
It is similar to Safe Mode Command Prompt in previous versions of Windows. But it works differently. For example not all commands are available. And not all drivers are loaded. And our driver is not loaded too.
Our driver must be loaded, because it encrypt/decrypt disk content. Without it disk content is unavailable.

How we can solve this problem? How driver can force Windows to load it in Advanced Startup Command Prompt? Probably we need to develop special type of driver, for this mode?
I cannot find detailed documentation about how Advanced Startup Command Prompt works. Is such documentation exist?

Answer (score 0):

just add a small unencrypted boot bcd/swap partition upon making your install image.  windows makes its own 300 meg partition too.  simple to build.

3 partitions after a diskpart clean

1 windows partition (installed upon w8 1st reboot on install)
2 ntfs partition unencrypted that holds the BCD, SWAP, some other stuff
3 a single VHD File, or more :), on a huge encrypted partition

use easy bcd to choose the vhd of your choice, if you go from disk to disk, all you need is the VHD and the original BCD that the Windows was installed into. Basically a windows installation ties to the BCD, cant move one vhd from one disk to another without the BCD.

Pro,Ultimate,Server, et al are vhd bootable